# How can i pick a image from gallery?

Tags: android

I am making a project in which in which i am using two `ImageView`s and i want to pick two different images from `gallery` and i want to set on two different `ImageView`s. I am able to pick one and set on one `imageview`. but i am not coming to understand that how i can do this in second `imageview` case?

The code i used is...

```
ImageView iv1,iv2;

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

        iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
        iv1.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
        iv2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(v.getId()==R.id.imageView21){
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
            }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            iv1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
```

---

Update 1...

It is giving problem, it is settingup image on both imageview even if i am trying to do for one...

```
public class LayoutDisplay2 extends Activity{

    ImageView iv1, iv2;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 = 1;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
            }
        });
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
        iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent in = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            iv1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in second",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("Second", "in second");
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            iv2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: visit http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/  also  https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

Comment: same as first imageview just change your request code for that in result.

Comment: @Achilles it seems it will work i try this and thanks all of you for giving your precious time. I have one more query how may i know may i save this image of two imageviews in gallery

Comment: can you explain properly??

Comment: @Achilles i made updation in code its giving a small problem i.e i am trying to set a image on a imageview but it is setting the same image on both imageview

Comment: yeah because you are assigning same value for RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 and RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2.. change into 1 and 2.

Comment: i got private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 = 1;
 private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 = 2;

Comment: @Achilles thanks it worked. I am making a project in which i can add two photos from gallery and i save this photo having two photos in gallery now. How may i save this?

Comment: if my suggestion helped you then you can accept my below answer.

Comment: @Achilles This code is running
1. I am able to set picture on iv1
2. I am able to set picture on iv2
3. When i again click on iv2 and try to change the picture on iv2 it gives exception..i.e. 04-16 16:43:57.626: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:343)
04-16 16:43:57.626: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):  at com.app.LayoutDisplay2.onActivityResult(LayoutDisplay2.java:96)
04-16 16:43:57.626: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)

Comment: have you try removing first picture when you set second time?

Comment: no i didn't.. if I set picture on iv1, When i again click on iv1 and try to change the picture on iv1 it doesnot gives exception. In this case there is no picture set on iv2

Comment: i tested it..and its working properly.. no errors.

Comment: @Achilles yes i used this code try{
   iv2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }  and its working fine on my side also

Comment: then what is your issue now.?

Comment: Now i got a view in which there are two different images. I want to make this view as a single image( in which there are two images at iv1 and iv2) and i want to save this single image in gallery. Can you please tell what must i do for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below:

```
ImageView iv1, iv2;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 = 1;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
    iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
        }
    });
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
    iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent in = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        iv1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in second",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Second", "in second");
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        iv2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes in your code.

1. You have given same id for both of the imageviews.

   ```
   iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView21);

   iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
   ```

Change this to:

```
    iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView21);

    iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
```

1. Make changes as below

   ```
   if(v.getId()==R.id.imageView21){
       Intent i = new Intent(
               Intent.ACTION_PICK,
               android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

       startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE_1);
   }   
   else if(v.getId()==R.id.imageView22){
       Intent i = new Intent(
               Intent.ACTION_PICK,
               android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

       startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE_2);
   }
   ```

Comment: i made updation in code its giving a small problem i.e i am trying to set a image on a imageview but it is setting the same image on both imageview

Comment: Oh. I got the solution. Just give the RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 and RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE2 different values. Dont give the same value 1 to both.

Comment: This code is running 1. I am able to set picture on iv1 2. I am able to set picture on iv2 3. When i again click on iv2 and try to change the picture on iv2 it gives exception..i.e. 04-16 16:43:57.626: E/AndroidRuntime(5043): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:343) 04-16 16:43:57.626: E/AndroidRuntime(5043): at com.app.LayoutDisplay2.onActivityResult(LayoutDisplay2.java:96) 04-16 16:43:57.626: E/AndroidRuntime(5043): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)

Comment: Please give the complete exception trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this image-chooser-library-1.2.9.jar

Is simple and easy

```
imageChooserManager = new ImageChooserManager(this, ChooserType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE);
imageChooserManager.setImageChooserListener(this);
imageChooserManager.choose();
```

Follow on this link you may get answer.

https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2013/03/easy-image-chooser-library-for-android.html

Comment: i am able to pick image from gallery and able to set on iv1 and i want to pick image from gallery and want to set on iv2 also.

Comment: I think you want to do Open Gallery and select two image at time and set one in IV1 and second in IV2 Right ?

Comment: @ Amit Prajapati i want to select image on click of particular imageview and set one in IV1 and second in IV2